# Obtain partial IMAP text part

Tags: python, imap, imaplib

I have an email interface client, and I am using IMAP for my requests. I want to be able to show, in real-time, basic email data, for a list view.

As in, for example, the GMail list  view. For that, I need to do an IMAP request to obtain the subject of all emails, the date of all emails, etc. This works so far.

The problem is, I want to also show the first characters of the body text. If I use the `BODYSTRUCTURE` call to obtain the index of the `text/HTML` part it takes too long (for emails with thousands of characters it might take well over a second per email, while using only the subject/date/etc calls takes about 0.02 seconds max.

I tried using the `BODY[INDEX]<0.XYZ>` bytes where `XYZ` is the number of the first bytes we want to obtain, but to my dismay, it takes as long as using the `BODY[INDEX]` call. Sometimes even more.

Is there another way to obtain the first text characters, but in a quick manner? If I want to list 300 emails on my interface I cannot afford to spend 1 second per email just to obtain the first text characters.

I'm using Python with imaplib for this, even though probably not relevant.

Answer (score 3):

there exists a raw fetch command defined in [IMAP RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.4.5).

```
FETCH 2 (BODY[]<0.size>)
```

for example if you want to fetch first 100 bytes of mail then you can fire the command as

```
FETCH 2 (BODY[]<0.100>)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to fetch the beginning of the first textual part of a message, you will have to parse the BODYSTRUCTURE. After you obtain the part ID of the desired textual part, use the `BODY[number]<0.size>` syntax.

The suggestion given in the other answer will fail on multipart messages (like if you have a `text/plain` and `text/html`, which is most common format today.

Comment: Yes. That is what I was assuming with the above answer. Using BODY[INDEX] instead of BODY[], where INDEX is the index of the text/HTML text part.