# Send large size data with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, download, webserver

I need to send to the customers a raw emails via my rails app.

When they click a link, a new page must open and they need to be able to see the source code of an email. I have a lot of cases where there are emails really big (even 40/50 mb), and it takes a lot of time to server to send it. 
E.G.

> I have an email with 3 attachments, the total size is 30mb. My
>   controller method it takes 700 ms to process it and to retrieve the
>   raw source from imap server, but in the broswer, it takes up to 5
>   seconds. (2.5 to the first byte, 2.5 to download it).

Right now I just send the string with the render method. Is there a better way? where I am losing all that time?

To be more clear:

With the word 'send' I mean when the server has to 'send' the source code to the browser so the suer can visualize it

Comment: *"I need to send [...] raw emails"* - do your customers really want to see the email's raw source code?

Comment: yes. And anyway, the same problem is with attachments... how can I make an attachment downloadble with rails?

Answer (score 0):

What about storing attachments on your server and include in email only links to those attachments? This way your emails will be blazingly fast and clients may download attachments separately. If you don't want to store files on your server, you may use Amazon S3 or some other cloud storage (there are many in these days).

To ease file uploading, I'd recommend you [`carrierwave`](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/tree/0.5-stable#carrierwave) library, [Amazon S3](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/tree/0.5-stable#using-amazon-s3) integration goes from the box.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use Delayed Job: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job or Sidkiq: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq

When the job is in processing state, you can mark that email as `Sending....` and once the background job is completed you can mark it as `Sent`

Hope this helps

Comment: Maybe I have explained my problem badly, with the word 'send' I mean when the server has to 'send' the source code to the browser so the suer can visualize it

Comment: So if I am not wrong, you want your rails app to receive an email, with big attachments and show it to the user.

Comment: Yes... the part of the reception is already made. Now, I have the base64 encode of the file, and want the user to be able to download it

Comment: Which gem/library you are using to receive email in your rails app?

Comment: The imap library that talks to my imap server

Comment: How about you write a cron job to to read incoming emails and store your attachments in your local directory and read email body separately
`body = imap.fetch(message_id,'BODY[TEXT]')[0].attr['BODY[TEXT]']`

Answer (score 0):

I think you could benefit from looking into solutions for HTTP streaming, which would allow you to start sending data while still processing the request.

This is difficult with Rack based servers, so Rails might have some issues with this approach.

Another approach is to try and split the raw source into chunks and request each chunk using Ajax.

This will allow your app to be more responsive and offer a better user experience. This is also known as a perceived performance approach, since the user experiences the app as more responsive even if it takes the same amount of time to load.

If I were trying to resolve the issue, I would look into an Ajax solution that would allow me to leverage [IMAP's partial fetch feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15792128/obtain-partial-imap-text-part), referenced in [it's RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.4.5).

It's possible to write a simple server side API that fetches a part of an email or returns a signal when there is no more to download and than use Javascript to request the data from the server until the 'no more data' return value is received.

This would allow you to display the downloaded data as it's being received.